# Create table exception

Tags: sql, hive

While running the following commands:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE zips (zip int, city String) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION ’/tutorial/input';
```

I got an exception:

> mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification

I searched about the issue and I tried to use OCT code like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE zips (zip int, city String) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' LOCATION ’/tutorial/input';
```

I am new to Hive. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: maybe stupid question but is the quote between location and /tutorial correct?

Comment: `ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054' LOCATION ’/tutorial/input';` Did you intend to use different quotes after location?

Comment: describe formatted any other existing table and you will see the correct location format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `’` to `'`:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE zips (zip int, city String) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/tutorial/input';
```

You should avoid copying code and instead type it. It allows to better understand how it works and develop muscle memory.